# Visualize which \if this \fi associates to

Tags: best-practices

For example, I use macros `\ifbook` and `\ifslide`. Because both can be closed by `\fi`, it's easy to lose track which `\if*` this particular `\fi` points to. They can be nested too, which makes things harder.

I end up manually associate them like the following. So far it's been working but I found it cumbersome and error-prone.

```
\ifbook
:
\fi %%ifbook

\ifslide
:
\fi %%ifslide
```

Better idea is appreciated.

Comment: presumably you mean `\ifbook` not `/ifbook` ?

Comment: You mean `\fi` etc., not `/fi` ???

Comment: What about indenting the intervening material by some fixed amount, say two spaces? And if you nest them, indent the inner part by another two spaces, etc.

Comment: Isn't this down to personal preference and therefore opinion-based?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I don't find this necessary, but what about `\let\bookfi\fi` to make it more 'outstanding'?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifbook

\let\bookfi\fi


\booktrue
\begin{document}


\ifbook
Yay!
\else
Nope
\bookfi

\bookfalse
\ifbook
Yay!
\else
Nope
\bookfi


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd have been tempted to make that `\koobfi`. But I think the temptation would pass, real quick.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: You're more tempted than me. ;-)

Comment: and what do you guys do about `\else`'s ? `\bookkoob`?